# scanbd has 30 seconds delay when running as service on Archlinux

Tags: raspberry-pi, archlinux, sane

I've set up sane/scanbd on an arm box (similar to raspberry pi) with Archlinux. The scanbd is configured to scan a page from the scanner when the `scan` button is pressed. Everything works fine when running scanbd directly from command line as `scanbd -d1 -f`. However, when I run it as a service (with [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd)), there's a delay of about 30-40s before scanning starts (although it scans eventually).

I've followed [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Scanner_Button_Daemon) guide to install/configure scanbd.

I left the `scanbd.conf` as the default configuration. My `test.script` looks like this:

```
scanimage --batch-count=1 --resolution 150 --source="ADF Duplex" --batch=/tmp/$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)_%02d_out.tiff --format=tiff
#merge into multipage tiff
tiffcp -c lzw /tmp/*out.tiff /tmp/output.tiff
#convert to pdf
tiff2pdf -z /tmp/output.tiff > /tmp/output.pdf

rm /tmp/*.tiff
chmod 755 /tmp/output.pdf
mv /tmp/output.pdf /home/scanner/output.pdf
```

Any ideas as to why the massive delay is introduced?

Comment: Did you determine scanner device type manually ? Auto-detect-device got a lot delay for scanning bus/busses .

Comment: if it was the auto-detect issue, then running scanbd from command line would have the same delay, oddly it does not.

Comment: Try it first in the terminal, it will run late if there is no service record. In addition, some **ttyAMx**  connections require additional configuration in the system. The Terminal can provide this, but applications will not work like system applications!

Comment: Short tricks : How to prepare bus/bus_block_size on plugin ? Filling buffer and read `EOF` are different methods.

Comment: To add more debug output, including timings, use `export SANE_DEBUG_DLL=255 && scanimage -L`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out a workaround. The delay comes from scanbm.socket service.

Steps to fix:
1. disable the socket:

```
systemctl stop scanbm.socket
systemctl disable scanbm.socket
```

2. remove `net` as the device from `/etc/scanbd/sane.d/dll.conf`
3. remove scanbm dependency from the scanbd service:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/dbus-de.kmux.scanbd.server.service
[Unit]
Description=Scanner button polling Service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/scanbd -f -c /etc/scanbd/scanbd.conf
#ExecReload=?
Environment=SANE_CONFIG_DIR=/etc/scanbd/sane.d
StandardInput=null
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
#NotifyAccess=?

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
#Also=scanbm.socket <-- comment out this line
Alias=dbus-de.kmux.scanbd.server.service
```

4. restart the scanbd service: `systemctl restart scanbd`